# Terraform auth problem with the google_firebase_project resource

Tags: firebase, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I've imported my firebase project as a terraform resource, but got this when ran `terraform plan`:

```
│ Error: Error when reading or editing FirebaseProject "projects/myproject": googleapi: Error 403: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the firebase.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. If you are getting this error with curl or similar tools, you may need to specify 'X-Goog-User-Project' HTTP header for quota and billing purposes. For more information regarding 'X-Goog-User-Project' header, please check https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/774686551450",
│       "service": "firebase.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]
│ 
│   with google_firebase_project.default,
│   on main.tf line 27, in resource "google_firebase_project" "default":
│   27: resource "google_firebase_project" "default" {
```

If I set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var to a service account of that project, it seems to work, but I'd like to avoid it as it is required to re-export that variable each time I'm changing environment.

I've authenticated to `gcloud` via my user, which is admin for all the relevant project.

Comment: If you have already created the service account for that project, could you try authenticating the Cloud SDK with `gcloud auth activate-service-account service_account_email --key-file=/path/to/your/service/account/keyfile.json`
More info here - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: @st_rt_dl_8 I want to avoid the service account altogether, as it require to switch each time I'm deploying to a different environment.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm facing the same issue. Service account is not an option for me either

Answer (score 1):

As an external tool, terraform requires *some* method of authenticating with GCP. You have only two options:

1. A service account with the required permissions.
2. A GSuite user or group with the required permissions.

One service or group or user account can be granted permissions on multiple projects, although this has security implications (blast radius mainly) and I wouldn't recommend it.

Switching accounts when working with different projects might be annoying, but is currently the best way.

If you're working with GKE, you may be able to leverage their workload identity feature. I'm not exactly sure about how this works, but I believe it enables automatic switching to the correct service account depending on the workload. Ultimately, separate service accounts are still required.